# Simple way of fetching the number of check ins and display them on website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web, checkin

Dear fellow coffee junks,

I am new to the Graph and have been profiting from this forum a lot, also contributed at least a little. I dug myself into the documentation these days to find an easy way to fetch the number of my groups check ins to display them on my website. I found it quite hard to understand the facebook docs and wanted to ask if anyone of you has ever done that, can provide a little code, advice, ideas?

What I am looking for is as simple as for example displaying a div that says: x People have visited Bordemundo B&B so far - wheras x stands for the number of check ins provided by the Facebook Api.

Saludos desde Chile!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do an HTTP GET to http://graph.facebook.com/Bordemundo

and read the "checkins" property.

```
{
   "id": "197019950350220",
   "name": "Bordemundo B&B Puerto Varas - www.bordemundo.com",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/157920_197019950350220_431834135_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/Bordemundo",
   "likes": 123,
   "category": "Hotel",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "www.bordemundo.com",
   "username": "Bordemundo",
   "description": "Das Bed and Breakfast Bordemundo liegt im S\u00fcden Chiles, in Puerto Varas, Patagonien.\nWir vermieten Zimmer in zwei traditionell eingerichteten chilenischen Caba\u00f1as und einem\npatagonischen Bauernhaus.  Unsere G\u00e4ste genie\u00dfen einen wundersch\u00f6nen Ausblick auf den Llanquihue-See und die angrenzenden Vulkane. Mit einer voll ausgestatteten amerikanischen K\u00fcche und gro\u00dfem Wohnzimmer mit Kamin bleibt kein Wunsch offen.\nFr\u00fchst\u00fcck gibt es in Gemeinschaft, privat zu Euch auf das Zimmer oder auf einer wilden Wiese mit unvergesslichem Vulkan-Panorama. Dabei sind viele Zutaten und Produkte selbstgemacht und selbst organisch angebaut. Zum Bordemundo geh\u00f6ren ein Strand und vier Hektar naturbelassenes Land, das viele Ruhepunkte bietet. Obwohl mitten im Nirgendwo, braucht ihr nur wenige Minuten in den Stadtkern Puerto Varas. Zum Pazifik nach Puerto Montt sind es keine 20 Minuten. In der Gegend bieten sich unz\u00e4hlige aufregende Freizeitgestaltungsm\u00f6glichkeiten - Lakecrossing, Kayak, Kanu, Wasser-Jetski, Motorradfahrten, Wanderungen, Climbing und vieles mehr. Besucht uns und habt eine sch\u00f6ne Zeit. Wir freuen uns auf Euch!\n\nBordemundo Bed and Breakfast is situated in Puerto Varas, Patagonia, in Southern Chile.\nWe rent rooms in two traditional Chilean Caba\u00f1as and a Patagonian farm house. Our guests\nenjoy a beautiful view on lake Llanquihue and four volcanos. Our caba\u00f1as feature fully equipped American kitchens as well as huge living rooms with chimneys. Breakfast is served in a community area, on your room or at a cosy play in midst of a wild lakeside meadow with a wonderful view on volcano Osorno. Bordemundo is surrounded by a 4 hectare estate, featuring a lot of wild nature and cosy places to relax. Furthermore, we provide access to a private beach. Though being situated in the middle of nowhere you are only a few minutes away from the centre of Puerto Varas and no more than 20 minutes from Puerto Montt and the Pacific Ocean. Right at your doorstep there are dozens of activities to explore the Patagonian beauty ranging from lake crossing, canoing, motorbike tours, trekking tours to climbing and a lot more. Show up and enjoy the time of your life. See you soon at Bordemundo.",
   "location": {
      "street": "Camino a Ensenada,km3",
      "city": "Puerto Varas",
      "country": "Chile",
      "zip": "5550000 Region Los Lagos",
      "latitude": -41.33219,
      "longitude": -72.97047
   },
   "parking": {
      "street": 0,
      "lot": 1,
      "valet": 0
   },
   "public_transit": "Bus - Direction Ensenada/ Petrohue",
   "phone": "0056-9-62919443",
   "general_info": "green tourism:\ncrystal-clear water from a fount on our land,\norganic growing of food served as breakfast,\n4 hectares-estate of Patagonian nature in it's natural state,\nprivate beach in front of the caba\u00f1as,\nhuge panorama windows with view on Llanquihue, four volcanos,\ncosy rooms, comfortable beds, chimneys and American kitchens, fully equipped, access to garden, working holidays possible for any kind of craftsmen and artists",
   "can_post": true,
   "checkins": 3,
   "talking_about_count": 31
}
```

Comment: Thx DMCS, yeah, this makes sense, I had this on my radar, I already used the facebook reader to display the information but with which I struggle is how to query it by code. I guess this is the "Do a http get" - do you have a (beginner`s) place to refer me to referring to this problem?

Comment: Client side with Javascript will be the easiest. Or you can do it server-side.  Depends upon your server's programming language as to the syntax or examples.   For Javascript SDK just `FB.api("/Bordemundo", function(response){//do something with response data});'`